# Fourier series coefficients without integrals

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, signal-processing

A question in my lecture was:
Determine the Fourier series coefficients of the signal x(t) = sin<sup>3</sup>(πt)
And a hint was that I didn't need to evaluate any integrals (the Fourier analysis functions) to obtain my answer.
I know A<sub>0</sub> = 0 because this is the average over a period of a sine function. But how do I evaluate any other A<sub>k</sub> by intuition?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: What is $\sin 3\theta$?

Comment: (It's not really intuition, just not integrals - use formula you know from trigonometry.)

Comment: Alternatively, you can write $\sin x=\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{ix}+e^{-ix}\right)$ to get coefficients.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So are the coefficients for sin^3 x the same as for sin x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using
\begin{align}
\sin^{3}(x) &= - \frac{1}{8 i} \, \left( e^{i x} - e^{-i x} \right)^{3} \\
&= - \frac{1}{ 8 i} \, ( 2 i \sin(3 x) - 6 i \sin(x)) \\
&= \frac{3}{4} \, \sin(x) - \frac{1}{4} \, \sin(3 x)
\end{align}
then it is determined that there are only two non-zero coefficients of a Fourier Sine series expansion.

Since the Fourier Sine series is given by
$$F_{s}(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_{n} \, \sin(n x) = B_{1} \, \sin(x) + B_{2} \, \sin(2 x) + B_{3} \, \sin(3 x) + \cdots$$ 
then for $F_{s}(x) = \sin^{3}(x)$ it is determined that $B_{2} = 0$, $B_{n} = 0, n \geq 4$, and $B_{1} = \frac{3}{4}$, $B_{3} = - \frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Thank you! But how do I obtain the coefficients from this transformed formula? (sorry if this is an obvious question)

Comment: @ThijsH By comparison to the Fourier Sine series.